# How can I preload these images to make this function smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am swapping out a background image about every 2 seconds, for multiple seconds.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  /*QUAD 1 ANIMATIONS*/

  $(".quad-1")
    .delay(2000)
    .queue( function(one){
    $(this).css('background', 'url("img/p-2.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom/cover transparent'); 
    one();
  });

  $(".quad-1")
    .delay(2000)
    .queue( function(one){
    $(this).css('background', 'url("img/p-3.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom/cover transparent'); 
    one();
  });

  $(".quad-1")
    .delay(2000)
    .queue( function(one){
    $(this).css('background', 'url("img/p-4.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom/cover transparent'); 
    one();
  });  

  $(".quad-1")
    .delay(2000)
    .queue( function(one){
    $(this).css('background', 'none'); 
    one();
  });     
});
```

The animation therefore becomes flash because a new image has to be loaded into the DOM and then resized.

I can't use a sprite for this because the positioning of the background images is relative using right top/cover

How do I preload the image in question before each function?

Comment: you'll want to preload them upfront, otherwise there will be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your html, make a div that's set to hidden, and add the img tags to them like as follows:

```
<div style="display:none;">
   <img src="img/p-2.png" />
   <img src="img/p-3.png" />
   ....
</div>
```

You can find additional methods here : 
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html

Comment: no dice. Even switched my js to .ready to $(window).bind("load", function() {

Comment: Have you tried some of the other methods in the link?  Sometimes when the page loads and your script runs to fast, it may call the images before they're pre-loaded.  In the link, you could add option 1 to the head and it should load the images before the onReady is fired.